# Trying to return data from PHP with JSON to Android.....

Tags: java, php, android, json

Trying to return data from PHP with JSON to Android.  below is my php script

```
<?php 
#
print(json_encode("[name=john]"));
#
?>
```

But I am getting the error in java : ERROR/log_tag(907): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at character 0 of

Comment: i still get this error: 09-07 07:12:28.309: ERROR/log_tag(907): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at character 1 of {"name":"john"}

Answer (score 5):

`json_encode` needs an actual object or array to encode into json format.  Also, it's good practice to set the content type for the response header.  Try this:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    print json_encode(array('name' => 'john'));
?>
```

I don't know much about the java side.  As [nikc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109302/nikc), mentioned, [json_encode](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) changes associative arrays to json objects and numerical arrays into json arrays.

Comment: I still get this error: 09-07 07:12:28.309: ERROR/log_tag(907): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at character 1 of {"name":"john"}

Comment: An associative array will naturally be encoded as an object and not an array when converting to JSON.

Comment: @SJS The answer is in your reply... parse it as a JSON object and not a JSON array.

Answer (score 1):

you are encoding a json array with json_encode.  In json [ ](square brackets) stands for array and { }(curley brackets) for object. Using the sample given by [enobrev],  returns a json object  rather then json array.

Your solution in this case would be in android to call

```
//Example of the content of result:
// {"name":"john"} This would be the result returned from the restfull request
// This the above JSON would be stored in a variable of type String.
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result); //JSONObject's constructor accepts a string as parameter
```

When you have the object you can then write:

```
obj.getString("name");
```

This will retrieve the value from which the key is "name"

An example of its usage can be:

```
Toast.makeText(context, obj.getString("name"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

which returns john.

Because the error you got implies that you are trying to make a json array out of a json object.